# How can I call my pallets and it functions in a smart contract?

Tags: substrate-node-template, smart-contract, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-contracts-node

How can I call my pallet functions from a smart contract?

For example I have a pallet with name `dex`, this pallet has some function with name A , B , C. Now I want to call and use this functions in my smart contract. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check this example [A Substrate node demonstrating two-way interactions between the runtime and Ink! smart contracts.](https://github.com/justinFrevert/Runtime-Contract-Interactions/)

It shows you a demo for both scenarios: [Pallet-to-contract](https://github.com/justinFrevert/Runtime-Contract-Interactions/#pallet-to-contract) and the one you are looking for: [Contract-to-pallet](https://github.com/justinFrevert/Runtime-Contract-Interactions/#contract-to-pallet)